# Which is better way to create a react app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, vite

I have been working with reactjs from last 7-8 months, I have always used `create-react-app` to get started with any react application. but, by exploring more ways to get started with a react application I came to know there is a thing called `vite` which is I guess is providing a faster and leaner development experience for modern web projects.

I used it once till now, *not in production yet* as I am not very confident about it. So, which is a better way to get a simple template for react app. which is also better in production environment. Does using any one affects in production?

Comment: i am wondering the same things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRA uses webpack to handle its core functionalities. In the development webpack repeats the bundling process every time there is a change in the code. As a result, when your source code grows larger, everything becomes sluggish. The time it takes to serve a dev server and build your projects increases significantly.

Vite only needs to pre-bundle your dependencies using esbuild the first time you start development before it begins to serve your app.
Vite doesn’t need to bundle the entire app or transpile the modules and code before starting a dev server; transpiling is done on-demand, thus making it significantly faster than CRA.

[https://blog.logrocket.com/vite-3-vs-create-react-app-comparison-migration-guide/#:~:text=Vite%20and%20CRA%20are%20not,and%20which%20modules%20are%20supported](https://blog.logrocket.com/vite-3-vs-create-react-app-comparison-migration-guide/#:%7E:text=Vite%20and%20CRA%20are%20not,and%20which%20modules%20are%20supported).

Comment: Is the **only** advantage of vite over CRA a development server? Then thats not enough to switch